# Collision Detection Libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision

I have a problem with collision detection using TiledMap.
In tiledMap I have a rectangleMapObject and then I have a sprite that stays in the same camera matrix of camera that render that TiledMap.
The sprite moves upward.

This is the main code:

```
//tiledmap is my object that wrapper tiledmap class



public static boolean collision(Sprite car){

            ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> objectsLayer=getObjectsFromLayer("layerCollision");
            return objectsLayer.get(0).getRectangle().overlaps(car.getBoundingRectangle());
     }


     public static ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> getObjectsFromLayer(String layerName){

            ArrayList<RectangleMapObject> array=new ArrayList<RectangleMapObject>();

            MapLayer layer=tiledMap.getMap().getLayers().get(layerName);
            if(layer!=null){
            MapObjects objects=layer.getObjects();

            for(MapObject object : objects)
                if (object instanceof RectangleMapObject) 
                    array.add(((RectangleMapObject) object));
            }
            return array;
        }
```

My problem is that the first method returns always false even when the sprite is above the rectangle.

What is that mistake?

to give it a try I have also done this:

```
return car.getBoundingRectangle().overlaps(car.getBoundingRectangle());
```

but it returns always false

Comment: Check overlaps in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Rectangle.java If the rectangles are exactly the same size and position it seems to me overlaps will return False.

Comment: ok for because then when the rectangles are different (size and position) I do not detect the collision

Comment: you are just checking the first object ... `objectsLayer.get(0)`.

Comment: yes because in this case I have only one object in those layer